# How to insert array elements in table format using typescript in HTML

Tags: html, css, typescript

I have written a code for insertion sort in typescript and i got values in html page..

My problem is i want to display them in a row as a table with the sorted values.

dynamically the columns should be created by taking the length of array..

please help me.....

```js
<!--app.component.ts-->

enter code here
import {
  Component
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  numericArray: Array < number > = [1, 2, 6, 9, 13, 25, 100, 22, 76, 222];
  sorrtedArray: Array < number > = this.numericArray.sort((n1, n2) => n1 - n2);


  insertion_Sort(arr) {
    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] < arr[0]) {
        //move current element to the first position
        arr.unshift(arr.splice(i, 1)[0]);
      } else if (arr[i] > arr[i - 1]) {
        //leave current element where it is
        continue;
      } else {
        //find where element should go
        for (var j = 1; j < i; j++) {
          if (arr[i] > arr[j - 1] && arr[i] < arr[j]) {
            //move element
            arr.splice(j, 0, arr.splice(i, 1)[0]);

          }
        }
      }
    }
    return arr;
  }
  result = this.insertion_Sort([1, -2, 6, 90, 13, 25, 100, 22, 76, 222]);
}
```

```html
<!--app.component.html-->



<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
</div>
<table>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        {{result}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The hard part is behind you!

Now you just have to write a `for` loop that iterates over the columns (from 1 to the given array's length) and every iteration prints a `<TD>` with the current element inside. Something like this:

```js
var array = [1,2,3];  // As an example

var ans = "<TABLE><TR>";
for(i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    ans += "<TD>" + array[i] + "</TD>";
}
ans += "</TR></TABLE>"

document.write(ans);  // Or return it, depends on your specific need
```